# Add first article to magento cart

Tags: sql, magento, migration

We have made a Magento migration from one server to another (retains title) and everything works fine except when you add the first item to the cart gives the following error:

```
Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(130): Zend_Currency->toCurrency('12,40')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX..com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX..com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX..com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX..com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX..com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXXX..com/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

I have looked at the log path but does not give me more information, know that it can be?

Thanks

Comment: what was the error? you only provided trace ?

Comment: the trace is the error I get when accessing checkout cart

Comment: above this trace, there should be an error message. What was that message

Comment: Sorry... "Value '12,40' has to be numeric"

Comment: provide full error message. its not clear

Answer (score 0):

12,40 is not a numeric, it is a string... do you use any module like ajax cart, a currency modifier ?  if yes, check these modules because zend_currency will translate for you in you locale 12.40 into 12,40.

if 12,40 is the minimum amount of an order, consider changing the value in your config.